No audio devices in Ubuntu 23.10
I've just updated to 23.10 from 22.04 and after updating there are no audio devices listed in settings. I believe my system is using WirePlumber and PipeWire:
systemctl --user status pipewire.service wireplumber.service pulseaudio.service

    Unit pulseaudio.service could not be found.
● pipewire.service - PipeWire Multimedia Service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pipewire.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2024-05-04 23:14:53 +08; 19min ago
TriggeredBy: ● pipewire.socket
   Main PID: 3136 (pipewire)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 18739)
     Memory: 5.4M
        CPU: 179ms
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/pipewire.service
             └─3136 /usr/bin/pipewire

May 04 23:14:53 ds047 systemd[3057]: Started pipewire.service - PipeWire Multimedia Service.

● wireplumber.service - Multimedia Service Session Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/wireplumber.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2024-05-04 23:14:53 +08; 19min ago
   Main PID: 3138 (wireplumber)
      Tasks: 6 (limit: 18739)
     Memory: 4.7M
        CPU: 2.875s
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/wireplumber.service
             └─3138 /usr/bin/wireplumber

May 04 23:14:53 ds047 systemd[3057]: Started wireplumber.service - Multimedia Service Session Manager.
May 04 23:14:53 ds047 wireplumber[3138]: SPA handle 'api.libcamera.enum.manager' could not be loaded; is it installed?
May 04 23:14:53 ds047 wireplumber[3138]: PipeWire's libcamera SPA missing or broken. libcamera not supported.
May 04 23:14:53 ds047 wireplumber[3138]: inotify_add_watch() failed: Permission denied
May 04 23:14:53 ds047 wireplumber[3138]: inotify_add_watch() failed: Permission denied

wpctl does correctly show audio devices I would expect, that was previously shown in settings:
  Audio
 ├─ Devices:
 │      39. Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller [alsa]
 │  
 ├─ Sinks:
 │      40. Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller HDMI / DisplayPort 3 Output [vol: 1.00]
 │      41. Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller HDMI / DisplayPort 2 Output [vol: 1.00]
 │      42. Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller HDMI / DisplayPort 1 Output [vol: 1.00]
 │  *   43. Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller Speaker + Headphones [vol: 1.00]
 │  
 ├─ Sink endpoints:
 │  
 ├─ Sources:
 │      44. Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller Headset Mono Microphone + Headphones Stereo Microphone [vol: 1.00]
 │  *   45. Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller Digital Microphone [vol: 0.00]
 │  
 ├─ Source endpoints:
 │  
 └─ Streams:

Edit: added aplay -l output
aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 0: HDA Analog (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 3: HDMI1 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 4: HDMI2 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 5: HDMI3 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 31: HDA Analog Deep Buffer (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Edit: added inxi output
sudo inxi -A 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Audio
    driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
  API: ALSA v: k6.5.0-40-generic status: kernel-api

Screenshot of sound settings

What does aplay -l  gives for answer, and also search for Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller  in the forum, you might find an answer.

@amar I've modified my post with the output of aplay -l. Bluetooth audio devices don't show up as input or output in settings either.

What is the output of sudo inxi -A , and have you installed and tested all configuration of pavucontrol?  sudo apt install pavucontrol

@amar I do have pavucontrol installed but PulseAudio is not installed, I only have WirePlumber and PipeWire. Have edited with the output.

Pls do not post screenshots from other sites, use the include picture in the body format of your question. If you run alsamixer in terminal and press F6 what are your choices?

@amar When I used the button to add a picture, I uploaded my picture and it automatically inserted the link.
The choices are "default" and the Intel driver "sof-hda-dsp"

Go to defult and see if it lists your sound card, if it does and MM is under the master press m to unmute it.

@amar Both default and the Intel sound card master and speaker are not muted. I have accidentally discovered that there is audio output through my speakers if I play videos through the Videos app, however Firefox is unable to output audio.

Download easyeffects with that you can see if firefox is muted and probably how to fix it Play a firefox with sound and go to easyeffects.

@amar Firefox is not muted, it does not show up on easyeffects. Using "Test Signal" does output sound.

Do not know if this will help, but worth a try https://support.mozilla.org/sv/kb/fix-common-audio-and-video-issues#w_allow-autoplay-of-media-with-sound, is your videos showing up in easteffects?
